# For Loop Case Selection Error

Tags: vba, excel, module

I have a problem regarding the case selected for loop.
The loop works perfectly fine the first time around, going all the way until case 18. However, whenever I try to restart the loop by typing "Y", it would restart the loop normally, but an error pops up whenever I try to enter a value into the message box.

I am confused as to why the code works the first time but not the second.

```
Sub MessageBoxFunction()

Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wsThis As Worksheet
Dim msgBox As Variant
Dim txt1, txt2 As String
Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
Dim i, iA, iB As Integer

Set rng1 = Range("A1")
Set rng2 = Range("A1")
txt2 = rng1.Value


Do Until IsEmpty(rng1)
Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

For i = 1 To 18
Select Case i
Case 1
    msgBox = InputBox("Do You Want To Input Information? (Y/N)")
    txt1 = CStr(msgBox)
    If InStr(1, msgBox, "N", 1) > 0 Then
        i = 17
        End If
Case 2 To 17
    msgBox = InputBox(txt2)
    txt1 = CStr(msgBox)
    iA = i - 2
    iB = i - 1
    rng1.Offset(0, iA).Value = txt1
    txt2 = rng2.Offset(0, iB).Value
Case 18
    msgBox = InputBox("Do You Want To Input Additional Information (Y/N)")
    txt1 = CStr(msgBox)
    If InStr(1, msgBox, "Y", 1) > 0 Then
        rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)
        txt2 = rng2.Value
        i = 1
        End If

End Select
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to use built-in function names as your variable name: `MsgBox` is a built-in function!

Comment: Oh yeah you are correct. Never noticed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the range on this line in `case 18`

```
rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)
```

This should work for you.

```
Sub MessageBoxFunction()

Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wsThis As Worksheet
Dim msgBox As Variant
Dim txt1, txt2 As String
Dim rng1 as Range, rng2 As Range
Dim i, iA, iB As Integer

Set rng1 = Range("A1")
Set rng2 = Range("A1")
txt2 = rng1.Value


Do Until IsEmpty(rng1)
Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

    For i = 1 To 18
    Select Case i
    Case 1
        msgBox = InputBox("Do You Want To Input Information? (Y/N)")
        txt1 = CStr(msgBox)
        If InStr(1, msgBox, "N", 1) > 0 Then
            i = 17
            End If
    Case 2 To 17
        msgBox = InputBox(txt2)
        txt1 = CStr(msgBox)
        iA = i - 2
        iB = i - 1
        rng1.Offset(0, iA).Value = txt1
        txt2 = rng2.Offset(0, iB).Value
    Case 18
        msgBox = InputBox("Do You Want To Input Additional Information (Y/N)")
        txt1 = CStr(msgBox)
        If InStr(1, msgBox, "Y", 1) > 0 Then
            Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)
            txt2 = rng2.Value
            i = 1
            End If

    End Select
    Next i

    End Sub
```

It should be this.

```
Dim rng1 as Range
Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)
```

Comment: I don't understand that. Why do I have to make another range object?

Comment: Why would the original object named rng1 not work when it has already been made?

Comment: In you original code you have not declared what type of variable 'rng1' is , so VBA assigns it as any one of these "Variant/Object/Range".  Without the "Set" , it becomes a "Variant" variable and you can't use the "Offset" feature which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: ? But did I not declare it as a Range at the very top of the code when I created it? Do I really need to create another Range in case 18?

Comment: Not declaring it only makes one on these "Variant/Object/Range" variant types.  Which is why you can use the "offset" feature on rng1. But as soon as you do not set the rng1 variable, it becomes a variant variable and therefore cannot treat it as a range anymore. And if you want to have the next set of data pasted into the line below the previous set, then yes you do have to set the rng1 variable again. That is , unless you rewrite the code.

Comment: I was under the impression that `Dim rng1, rng2 As Range` calls both as Range? Or is that wrong?

Comment: No,  that does not declare the `rng1`, only `rng2`. You need to write what type of variable after each one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a message box when asking Y/N instead of an input box:

```
If MsgBox("Do You Want To Input Additional Information", vbYesNo) = vbYes then
......
End if
```

Comment: What would I need to input for the function to work? Would Y/N work or does the user need to type Yes/No

Comment: This type of message box displays two buttons with Yes and No options, so the user will just have to click one of them.

Comment: Oh that's perfect. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Can you tell me why this seems to create an error?
'If msgBox("Do You Want To Input Information?", vbYesNo) = vbNo     Then'
            i = 18
            End If

Comment: I don't know how to make the comment look like code, my bad